# Matching any word behind a character (Vim)

Tags: regex, vim

Right now I have this:

```
/\w\+\(->\)\@=
```

Which matches a word immediately behind `->`

```
matchedWord->
```

How do I change that regex so it matches any word behind (on the left) `->` no matter if there's space or other characters?

Example:

```
matchedWord = ->

matchedWord = (x) ->
```

Comment: With the line `matchedWord = (x) ->`, do you want to match `x` or `matchedWord` or both?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger only `matchedWord`

Comment: Is `matchedWord` the first word on a line? Does it start on character one?

Comment: @René Nyffenegger yes first word of the line. They are variables.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger but sometimes there might be white space behind them (indentation).

Comment: Ok, so you want to use `\w\+\ze.*->`, see my edited answer.

Comment: I think you mean "in front of", not "behind".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you understand by *behind ->*

If this is to mean *after* then you want to try

```
->\s*\zs\w\+
```

The expression first searches for the literal `->` followed by any number (`*`) of spaces (`\s`). The following `\zs` then tells vim to actually start a match. The `\w\+` matches a word.

From your edit, I assume that you mean *behind* to mean *in front of*, so you want to try

```
 \w\+\ze\s*->
```

Almost the same logic as above, but I use `\ze` (end match) instead of `\zs`.

**Edit** so, you clarified that you want to match the first word in a line. In that case, you want

```
\w\+\ze.*->
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that one. What's the advantage of doing that over doing a look behind (`\@=`)?

Comment: I am not sure how `\zs` relates to `\@=` powerwise and performance wise, but I find `\zs` more cleanly.

Comment: weird, I get pattern no found. Do I have to add something to tell Vim to search through the whole file?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have an equal sign after your matched word. This is not matched by `\w`. Editing the answer

Comment: Thanks but `\w\+\ze.*->` still matching the `x` in `(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\s*` which will match 0 or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?\(->\)\@=
```

You can simply use this .`.*?` will match anythin upto `->`.

Comment: I get no matched pattern.